# Alignment issue in election nomination editor toolbar

Tags: bug, design, moderator-election

There is an alignment issue in the election nomination editor toolbar.

I have verified the issue, it is exists in the following browsers:

- Google Chrome Version 51.0.2704.103 m
- Mozilla Firefox Version 49.0.2
- Internet Explorer Version 11.0.9600.18205
- Operating System: Windows 8

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Nomination editor]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This alignment issue has been fixed in the [2017 Moderator election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/9) nomination page. Now the editor toolbar is aligned properly.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: 2017 election nomination page]